# Part of speech with "hacer a alguien hacer algo"

Tags: pronombres, categorías-gramaticales

I understand that the phrase "hacer a alguien hacer algo" means to make someone do something. My question is: is "alguien" the indirect or direct object? For example if someone were to say "I want to make him eat the food," would one say:

> Quiero hacerlo comer la comida.

or

> Quiero hacerle comer la comida.

Also, in either case, what part of speech is "comer la comida," or whatever someone is being made to do?

Comment: A mi se me suena muy raro la frase "hacerlo comer la comida". Sera mas natural usar el subjuntivo en caso asi: "hacer que coma la comida".

Comment: that "hacerle", "hacerlo" is well... leísmo and loísmo, in sapain would be "hacerle" and Mexico and other countires "hacerlo.

Comment: @Paul "Hacerlo/le comer" "Hacer/lo que coma" "Hacer que se coma" "Hacer que el coma" todas esas formas son correctas.

Comment: @Jaime it actually isn't a question of *leísmo* or *loísmo*.  That's when someone demonstrates a general tendency to use *le* as a direct object (relatively common, though only in Latin America when representing *usted*) or *lo* as an indirect object (quite uncommon).  But as the DPD notes, speakers actually switch between indirect and direct paradigms depending on the transitivity of the verb.  I'm slightly *leísta* and *laísta*, and so while I'll tend to use *le* always with men and *la* with women, with inanimate objects I make a clear *lo/la* vs. *le* distinction with *hacer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.  Per the DPD:

> Los verbos *hacer* y *dejar*, cuando tienen sentido causativo, esto es, cuando significan, respectivamente, ‘obligar’ y ‘permitir’, siguen la misma estructura que los verbos de influencia: «verbo causativo + complemento de persona + verbo subordinado». Tanto *hacer* como *dejar* tienden a construirse con complemento directo si el verbo subordinado es intransitivo: «*Él la hizo bajar a su estudio y le mostró el cuadro*» (Aguilera *Caricia* [Méx. 1983]); «*Lo dejé hablar*» (Azuela *Tamaño* [Méx. 1973]); y tienden a construirse con complemento indirecto cuando el segundo verbo es transitivo: «*Alguien lo ayudó a incorporarse, lo estimuló y hasta le hizo tomar café*» (JmnzEmán *Tramas* [Ven. 1991]); «*El alcaide de la cárcel le dejaba tocar el banjo todas las mañanas*» (Cela *Cristo* [Esp. 1988]).

Notice that it only says "tienden" and therefore there is no single approach — you will get variety, although the most common is to use a direct object when the verb is intransitive and the indirect object is transitive.  In your example, the verb is transitive (*comer **la comida***) so the most common would be to use *le*.

Likewise, to answer your other question, per the DPD, the term is a "subordinate verb".